# Find the roots that make an arithmetic progression for a parameter

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic-progressions

The problem: Find the values of $m$ for which all $4$ roots of the polynomial $(2m-1).x^4-2mx^2+1=0$ make an arithmetic progression. Then Find the roots for the found values of $m$.

What I've done: All $4$ to exist $2m-1$ must **NOT** $=0$ so $m =0,5$ not an answer. Also the $D>0$ $(m-1)^2>0$ so $1$ is not an answer. The roots of the polynomial are $1,-1,-\sqrt{-1/2m-1},\sqrt{-1/2m-1}$

Then for them to be an arithmetic progression each must = (the sum of other 2)/2 ? So I must solve some equations like : $1=(-1+\sqrt{-1/2m-1})/2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: the equation is a biquadratic, so if $x_1$ is a root then $-x_1$ is also a root. Then the $4$ roots must be of the form $-3r,-r,r,3r$ for some $r \gt 0\,$.

By Vieta's formulas the product of the $4$ roots is $9r^4=\frac{1}{2m-1}\,$, so $r = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}\,\sqrt[4]{2m-1}}$. Substituting this value in the equation gives a quadratic in $m\,$, with two real roots which both satisfy the condition.

Comment: Nice one never knew Vieta's formulas can be used for more then 2 roots.

Comment: @yoloexpectz They can, and there is more formulas than just the sum and product, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas#Basic_formulas) for example.